# how to know a contenteditable-div's y coordinate of scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, contenteditable

I am trying to make a online code editor using html's contenteditable `div`.

The user will edit their code in the `div`, which supports a maxium of `19` without scrolling the `div`.

What I want to do is to make a line number  for each line.

But as you can see, the line number won't change when the user is editing the code that overflows the `div` and makes the `div` scrolls. In order to fix this, I want to know the y-coordinate about scrolling of `div`. For example, if there's only 3 line, so the `div` doesn't scroll, the code returns `0`, if there's 100 line and the caret is currently in the 100th line, which makes the `div` scrolls, the code returns 100-19=`81`.

Here's the code:

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");

var row_text = document.getElementById("row-text");

function update(){
    //line numbers text. For example, if the top line's number should be 1, then it should return `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19`
    row_text.innerHTML="1\n2\n3";
}

setInterval(update, 1);
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #24292E;
}

#textbox-container{
 border: 0.5px white solid;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 
 left: 50%;
 position: relative;
 transform: translate(-248px, 2px);
}

#textbox{
 
 width: 480px;
 height: 292px;

 resize: none;
 left: 50%;
 position: relative;
 transform: translate(-233px, 2px);
 
 overflow: hidden;
 
 
 background-color: #24292E;
 
 color: white;
 
 font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
 
 outline: none;
 
 font-size: 12px;
 
 overflow: hidden;
}

p{
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 margin: 0px; 
 
 transform: translate(3px, 2px);
 
 font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
 
 font-size: 12px;
 
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="textbox-container">
   <p id="row-text"></p>
   <div id="textbox" cols="50" rows="5" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
  <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way possible to get the y-coordinate about scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
const logger = document.getElementById('logger');
const bottomLogger = document.getElementById('bottomLogger');

setInterval(() => {
  logger.value = textbox.scrollTop + 'px'; // Indentation from above
  loggerRow.value = textbox.scrollTop / 15; // row number
  
  bottomLogger.value = textbox.scrollHeight / 15;
}, 40)
```

```css
#textbox {
  background: aqua;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  
  max-height: 150px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id=textbox contenteditable rows=5></div>


<ul>
  <li>
    <input id=logger>
  </li>
   <li>
    <label>
      <strong>Row number</strong>
      <input id=loggerRow>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <strong>Bottom row</strong>
      <input id=bottomLogger>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[scrollTop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)
[scrollHeight API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)